# How can I add an outbound rule by windows advanced sercurity firewall on Windows 11?

Tags: permissions, firewall, windows-11

I wan to add a outbound rule by windows advanced sercurity firewall to block the `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ogh.exe` so that I can use ogh.exe offline. but when I do that, it can't add and told me **"The system is unable to access this file"**.
Is this because of insufficient permission? How can I set the permission correctly to do this?

I run `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WF.msc` in Adminnistor permission to create a outbound rule to block `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ogh.exe`, but it told me **"The system is unable to access this file"**. All `.exe` files in `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\` directory are the same.

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-files-and-folders-permissions-in-windows-10

Comment: What exact command have you used? Did you use a CMD that is Run as Administrator?

Comment: The permission owner is user, not the Administrator or System.

Comment: I use Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security (WFAS) to do that, and add the outbound rule with "new rule", it has GUI, not the CMD.